# file is not uploading from android to php server

Tags: java, php, android

Hi I wrote a code as shown below for uploading file from my android phone to php server. The application is running without any error, but the file is not uploaded to the server. Where did I go wrong ?

public class upload extends Activity {

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

String pathToOurFile = "sdcard/Android/data/file.pdf";
String urlServer = "http://mpss.csce.uark.edu/~smandava/upload.php";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //Exception handling
    }


}
```

}

//upload.php

```
$target_path = "http://mpss.csce.uark.edu/~smandava/files/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: It runs without errors because you catch all potential errors in your Java code.  Put a `Log` statement in the `catch` block of the code to see why it failed.

Comment: Can you the post the code in the PHP file? Also, what size is the file that you are trying to upload and the value of upload_max_filesize in php.ini? Is the PHP script known to work?

Comment: Sorry, the PHP code wasn't apparent, so you can ignore the request for code

Comment: @Haphazard I wrote the log statement it says                     06-22 15:50:05.119: ERROR/error tag(6613): /sdcard/Android/data/file.pdf

Comment: So, you have an error message.  Track down the problem using the stack trace.  ..Or paste the entire stack trace here and tell us what line number it is failing on.  Or, check out AndrewR's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $target_path should be a file system path, not a web url.

```
$target_path = '/home/smandava/public_html/files/'; // something like this
```